# How can I emit LLVM IR which compiles and runs a C++ function

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

For example, I want to define a function in C++:

```
int foo(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

Then what should I do to an IRBuilder to compile the `foo` function and add an module called `foo` into the IRBuilder?

Comment: http://releases.llvm.org/2.6/docs/tutorial/JITTutorial1.html

Comment: @sailfish009 This is insanely outdated.

Comment: sorry i couldn't find more latest one.

Comment: @sailfish009 I mean I want to directly compile this function to IR with LLVM/Clang, and insert it to a module or basic block. This tutorial is telling me to translate it to IR manually.

Comment: @YuhengZou how about this manual? let me know what you think. http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html

Answer (score 1):

**method A**)

compile with clang and use llvm API to parse bytecode

```
string cmd = "clang -emit-llvm a.cpp -o a.bc";
system(cmd);

Module* m = parseIRFile("a.bc", Err, Content);
```

**method B)**

use libclang

[Using libclang to Parse C++ (aka libclang 101)](http://shaharmike.com/cpp/libclang/)